# How to concat string from accept in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

the script:

```
accept ztablename
select count(*) from &ztablename||_tables 
/
```

It return ORA-00933 error.

I know **execute immediate(sql)** method, can not use the method?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't. Only with execute_immediate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the concatenation character, you just need the substitution variable and your fixed string. But you need to mark the end of the substitution variable name [with a period](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref458):

```
accept ztablename
select count(*) from &ztablename._tables 
/
```

Without the period, it would prompt for a variable using the too-long name `ztablename_tables`.